# Google Chrome extension development issue

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-account

I'm doing my own chrome extension for my own purposes. This extension has been working for 5 months successfully. Most probably it is not an issue with code of an extension.

My manifest.json (I'm working on mac)

```
 "manifest_version": 2,

 "name": "tab-switch-pt2",
 "description": "use option(alt) + 1...9 to change current tab. 9 — always last tab",
 "version": "1.0.0",

 "background": {
   "scripts": ["background.js"],
   "persistent": true
 },

 "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
     "js": ["content.js"]
   }
 ],

 "commands": {
   "my-change-tab:4": {
     "suggested_key": {
       "default": "Alt+4",
       "mac": "Alt+4"
     },
     "description": "Change to tab number 4"
   },
   "my-change-tab:7": {
     "suggested_key": {
       "default": "Alt+7",
       "mac": "Alt+7"
     },
     "description": "Change to tab number 7"
   },
   "my-change-tab:5": {
     "suggested_key": {
       "default": "Alt+5",
       "mac": "Alt+5"
     },
     "description": "Change to tab number 5"
   },
   "my-change-tab:8": {
     "suggested_key": {
       "default": "Alt+8",
       "mac": "Alt+8"
     },
     "description": "Change to tab number 8"
   }
 },

 "permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
}
```

Basically it is listening for Alt+(1...9) key, and changes the tab.
An issue is that these key binds does not work.

`chrome.commands.getAll((...args) => console.log(args, 'args'));`
returns this one

```
[
  [
    { description: 'Change to tab number 4', name: 'my-change-tab:4', shortcut: '' },
    { description: 'Change to tab number 5', name: 'my-change-tab:5', shortcut: '' },
    { description: 'Change to tab number 7', name: 'my-change-tab:7', shortcut: '' },
    { description: 'Change to tab number 8', name: 'my-change-tab:8', shortcut: '' },
  ],
]
```

This is when I'm signed in into my google account with all my other chrome extensions. I've thought that this is the problem with an extensions. So here what I've done:

Created new user, installed my extension, and it worked. An output of the same command above:

```
[
  [
    { description: 'Change to tab number 4', name: 'my-change-tab:4', shortcut: '⌥4' },
    { description: 'Change to tab number 5', name: 'my-change-tab:5', shortcut: '⌥5' },
    { description: 'Change to tab number 7', name: 'my-change-tab:7', shortcut: '⌥7' },
    { description: 'Change to tab number 8', name: 'my-change-tab:8', shortcut: '⌥8' },
  ],
]
```

So these keybinds actually worked for me. I've installed all extensions I had on my google account, and still it was working fine. Only when I've signed in (from this new google use) to my own google account, and when all sync were done, my extension stopped working. 
I've tried to reinstall chrome and to reset chrome settings, it all did not work. 
It feels like some settings or history or saved passwords or whatever is syncing from google account is conflicting with these keybinds. I have to mention that if I change some keybind to Alt+Z for example -- it works for my google account. So problem is only with Alt+1...9 keys

Comment: Check the shortcut customization in `chrome://extensions/shortcuts`

Comment: Wow. That works. There was an empty fields, I filled them with a desired key binds and it started to actually work like it has to. I didn't know about this page at all.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that page chrome://extensions/shortcuts could help. Assigning missing keybinds is more than enough